# Online payment for an application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have developed a trial application in Visual Basic.net
Currently, for the user to have a full version, they need to validate a key for their computer. My question is this: Is it possible, to incorporate a feature so that once the user has paid for the full version (via Paypal or any other online payment service), a key is automatically sent to them via email or via a download?

Is this easy to do in Visual Basic? If not, is there another automated way for a user to receive a valid key for an application after successful payment?
Has anyone done this? If so, what service do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this yourself in code but quite frankly you could also set about re-inventing the wheel.  What you are describing and what you want to achieve falls very neatly into the realms of software licensing and in truth you would probably want that to be as painless a process to yourself as is possible.  There are numerous solutions out there that you could use, and thankfully most also offer you the opportunity to try them out first.

I would suggest that you take a look at the infralution licensing system as an example of what is available at a reasonable cost (you can find out more from here http://www.infralution.com/licensing.html
)  I have found this to be a perfectly competent solution with excellent support when needed and much much easier that trying to build my own solution.